# Display JSON Data in a custom way and append to API in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

## The Situation

I'm currently decoding my array into JSON and display it
The structure is like that:

```
["value1","value2","value3","..."]
```

I want that data in an API request. So I thought of saving it to a variable and put that in the api request but I always get the error message invalid input format.
Since the API request needs the data like this:

```
API URL: "http://somedomain.com/api?=key:=searchfor=value1>>value2>>value3>>..."
```

My previous approach was:

```
"http://somedomain.com/api?=key:=searchfor=$mycustomarray"
```

I tried it with an array and JSON data but both wont work for the request.

### What I want to achieve

I want to get that data displayed in the format I need it for that API request.
Is there a way to get the JSON or Array in the desired format:
I should be put in the api request like:

```
[value1>>value2>>value3>>...]
```

I would appreciate any help

Comment: Use `implode` on your array. http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php that is `implode(">>",$yourArray);`

Comment: You can use implode and append all elements with '>>' in the array and send it as a string in the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php

$a = array("value1","value2","value3");

$b = implode('>>',$a);

print_r($b);

?>
```

Comment: Is there anything about JSON in your answer ? you should have used `json_encode` or `json_decode` with proper uses.

Comment: no he need to display the json or array in the format value1>>value2 that's why i didn't mention anything about json

Comment: He is using PHP in APIs so I guess he would be needing it to Callback APIs